# Is "packetize" a word?

Tags: neologisms

In the RF communications world, firmware takes data and "packetizes" it into frames. Is this really a word?

Comment: ***Packetize***: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/packetize

Comment: It is if enough people use it like one, and thousand of engineers and programmers do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "packetize" is a word.  It refers to the act of taking an object and breaking it up into small pieces, usually in order to send those pieces over a communication network to a destination where they will be reconstructed into the original object, or rather, a copy of the original object.

It is generally used in the context of digital [packet-switched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching) networks, as opposed to [circuit-switched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_switching) networks where the information is transmitted in one whole chunk over a dedicated connection instead of being broken into smaller pieces.

An example of a packet-switched network is the CAN bus in your car which transmits small chunks of data from one node to another, usually from sensors to the central computer and back.  These nodes all share the same physical wiring, but take turns transmitting frames (packets) of data on it.

An example of a circuit-switched network is the U.S. phone network of old, wherein operators would direct callers' phonecalls by physically connecting their phone to a dedicated circuit that would link them to their desired call destination.  While the call was connected, no other voice data could be transmitted on the dedicated line other than the data being sent between the two callers.